# "Error calling method on NPObject!" for flex deep linking

Tags: javascript, flash, flex4

I have a flex app hosted on domain A and served through a webpage at domain B.  I have enabled cross-domain scripting; in the webpage at domain B, I have the line

```
params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
```

and in the application code I have

```
flash.system.Security.allowDomain("*");
```

and for good measure,

```
flash.system.Security.allowDomain("keonehon.com"); // domain A
```

`ExternalInterface` calls seem to work; on startup the app calls a javascript function and the webpage calls a function back to pass a parameter in.

```
if (ExternalInterface.available){
                ExternalInterface.call("SWFLoadComplete");
                //lblMessage.text = "Data Sent!";
            }

function SWFLoadComplete(){
            callNewCarWithUser();
        }

        function callNewCarWithUser()
        {
          var user_id = document.getElementById('txtUserId').value;
          var room_id = document.getElementById('txtRoomId').value;
          getTheFlexApp().newCarWithUser(user_id, room_id);
        }
```

And this works correctly.  So, yeah.  Seems to be working fine, no?

HOWEVER, deep linking is not working, as setting the `#state=____` flex parameter in the URL (either by typing something in, or by navigating backward using the back button) causes a javascript error to be thrown at line 435 of `history.js`, a.k.a.

```
getPlayer().browserURLChange(flexAppUrl);
```

It seems like there is some sort of cross-domain security problem, even though I put in the line `flash.system.Security.allowDomain("*");`.  You can see that there are different behaviors when same-domain vs. cross-comain by comparing two pages with identical html and swf files, just cross-domain in one case and same-domain in the other:

cross-domain: http://keonehon.com/gongos/dreamcar.html.
same-domain: http://rails.mit.edu/gongos/dreamcar.html

What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is related at all, but I use to get this error all the time with ExtJS and the problem actually ended up being a simple syntax error, (missing bracket ] )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **allowScriptAccess** instead? (this might be case-sensitive if I remember correctly)

If that didn't work, it'd help to see more code or a sample page.